# how to interact with unspecified number of react child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a component which can contain any number of child components, and I want these child components, which contain input fields, to set those input fields to "disabled" when the state in the parent is changed. I've been attempting to use `React.cloneElement` with `React.Children.map` to modify the properties of the child elements, but it doesn't seem to be affecting anything.

Here's a simplified version:

```
# parent component
# assume that there's a @setState call in here somewhere
DisableableItem = React.createClass
  getInitialState: ->
    disabled: false
  render: ->
    <div>
      {
        React.Children.map @props.children, (child) =>
          React.cloneElement child, isDisabled: @state.disabled
      }
    </div>

# child component
ParameterizedOption = React.createClass
  getInitialState: ->
    disabled: @props.isDisabled
  render: ->
    <div className="parameterized-option">
      <label>{@props.text}</label>
      <div className="input-group input-group-sm">
        <input type={@props.inputType or "text"} className="form-control"
          placeholder={@props.initialInput or "00.00"}
          disabled={@state.disabled}></input>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And rendering it like:

```
React.render <DisableableItem>
    <ParameterizedOption text="hey" isDisabled=false />
    <ParameterizedOption text="hey" isDisabled=false />
  </DisableableItem>, document.body
```

So I'm `console.log`ging the output, and the state in the parent is getting modified when I want it to, but the children's props are not getting modified as I thought the `React.cloneElement` call would modify them (they're always false as they were at start). I've taken a look at [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30840258/encapsulation-with-react-child-components) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285923/reactjs-two-components-communicating), but I don't think they really apply, since `DisableableItem` doesn't know what its children are until they're given to it in the call to `React.render`, so it can't put `disabled={@state.disabled}` as one of the children's properties.

How would I reach in and modify these children's state? Am I misunderstanding what `cloneElement` is supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're copying the props to the state, which is some bad mojo. (https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html)

Just bind `props.disabled` directly to the element instead of copying it over to state.

---

Your current code:

```
getInitialState: ->
    disabled: @props.isDisabled
```

This will only work if you ensure you update `state.disabled` in `componentWillReceiveProps` to reflect the new `props.disabled` passed in.

If you're deadset on doing it your weird way: https://jsfiddle.net/1t8ew85x/

Comment: Rad. It turns out in my actual code (separate from the simplified version) I had another component in between and I didn't forward the change in props to the item that was actually getting disabled, so I was trying to modify the state to see if that would fix it. Thanks for the mojo help.